# Why won't my component detect a props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like I'm doing everything right?  It seems so simple i feel like I'm missing something.  Appreciate any help thank you

```
function App() {
  let jsonData = "a saved page from the database";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => {
        jsonData = "a different saved page from the database";        
      }}>
        Change jsonData
      </button>
      <Touchscreen
        key={jsonData}  // something i tried but still doesn't work
        jsonData={jsonData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export const Touchscreen = (props) => {  
  React.useEffect(() => {    
    console.log('jsonData: ', props.jsonData);  // won't trigger
  }, [props.jsonData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{props.jsonData}</span>  // never re-renders
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component redeclares`jsonData` on every re-render, you can't preserve the changes on `re-renders`. if you want to preserve something through the component lifecycle, [`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) is the place for it

```
function App() {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState("a saved page from the database");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => {
        setJsonData("a different saved page from the database");        
      }}>
        Change jsonData
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ah okay.  i read about state i just figured i could do it simply through a normal JS variable as well.  thank you

Comment: @user1189352 no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your jsonData as a property of the component **state** and then use `setState` to change the value. Calling `setState` will cause the component to re-render.

For more information about `setState`, take a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: gotcha.  i thought a simple JS variable would work as well.  thank you